# Image annotation tool that support annotation using existing CNN

Tags: data-annotations

I have trained a YoloV4 CNN. It's pretty good already. I want more images as training data but there is no point of manually annotate most of the stuff because CNN can do it for me. I could review and re-correct if there are any issues. Is there a image annotation tool/service that can do that? I'm currently using Supervisely. I also tried CVAT and VoTT Couldn't find such feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a tool `python` project to generate `supervisely` project using `darknet`. It's available on `github`.

https://github.com/s1n7ax/partially-annotate